# Django rest deferred task

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, celery

I want to write an API method that will do a specific task (e.g task/create)
But this task takes a long time.
I want the user to run the task (task/create) and then polled the service until it was executed (task/status).
As soon as the task is completed, the user can request the result (e.g task/result).
What tools can I use to implement such a pattern?
Can I put the task on a separate thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can put the task on a separate thread.

See [Celery for Django Tutorial](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Once you setup your celery you can call different tasks on separate threads to complete the task. Also, you can put a scheduled, periodical tasks as well.

Comment: Are there any other alternatives besides celery? I am having difficulty with it on my local machine. Maybe a standard python stream? Or is it a bad idea?

Comment: If you set it up correctly you should not have any issues, when you are on your project environment you can call ```celery -A  DJANGO_PROCEJT_NAME worker --loglevel=info``` and celery should run

Comment: @Pikachu did you manage to run your celery? if yes my answer is correct please mark it as answered to close the question :)